# Ice condensation on an air launched vehicle

Tags: ice

Following the recent failure of the Launcher One / 747 air launch from the UK I heard that during the pre-release commentary there was some discussion of the build up of ice and that the 747 was undergoing yaw manoeuvres, or a "fin wiggle", intended to help dislodge some of it.

It occurs to me that the environment around Cornwall would be very different to Mojave at most times of the year though I'm less sure how much the carrier aircraft flight path conditions would vary between the Atlantic release point south of Ireland and the Pacific release point off southern California.

Does anyone know if this manoeuvre has been used on previous Launcher One flights?

Old link:
[Link to Fin wiggle](https://www.ickonic.com/news-articles/r/spaced-out---virgin-orbit-satellite-mission-suffers-bungle-off-britain)

New link: [Same fin wiggle, different source](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/jan/09/uks-first-orbital-rocket-mission-takes-off-from-cornwall)

Comment: Yikes. The person who wrote that article clearly knows nothing about spaceflight. This seems to be a top-notch scientific journal, judging by the articles on the homepage about the power of ancient aliens and how to harness it, leylines and how their energy affects us, how UFOs prepare us for an invasion, King Arthur, etc.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm...not sure that was written by a person, actually.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Here's another link I'd found at the same time. Its the same news reported from commentary in the TV coverage.

Comment: My understanding is that there's quite a bit of icing on conventional rockets on the pad - what with cryogenic propellants and all - and it doesn't seem to hinder them. I would be surprised if air launches were any different in that regard.

Comment: @Cadence Yes, I follow the reasoning, hence the question. i.e. is attempt to remove it  special to LauncherOne or special to the Cornwall launch of LauncherOne